# Fluent NHibernate with Castle Windsor 2.0?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, exception, castle-windsor

It now makes sense that the versions aren't right.

I know I am using Castle Windsor 2.0 and I would like to use NHibernate with Fluent NHibernate - what versions do I need of these two?

**Edit** Ok, I think I got it wired up. I'm still having a version issue.
I now get this error when using the direct download from their site. The only library at 1.0.3 is the NHibernateFacility.

> {"Could not load file or assembly
>   'Castle.Core, Version=1.0.3.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=407dd0808d44fbdc' or
>   one of its dependencies. The located
>   assembly's manifest definition does
>   not match the assembly reference.
>   (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131040)":"Castle.Core,
>   Version=1.0.3.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=407dd0808d44fbdc"}

### *Old Problem*

Why would I be getting this?

> Method '{MethodName}' in type 'Class'
>   from assembly '{ClassLibrary},
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=' does not have an
>   implementation.

It compiles just fine and it is implemented. I don't even call that the class yet.

I am using IoC - Castle Windsor with Fluent NHibernate.

The interface I have to implement is `Castle.Facilities.NHibernateIntegration.Internal.IConfigurationBuilder`

Comment: Is it possible that you are compiling against a different version of a DLL than the one you are running against? Is there any remoting involved?

Comment: Its possible that the versions are different. I'm just not sure which ones go with which...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably a versioning conflict. Try getting the Castle and NH assemblies from the [Castle build server](http://www.castleproject.org:8090/?guest=1).

Comment: And how do you download from there?

Comment: re: fluentnh: get the fluentnh sources and build against the nh dll included with castle.
re: downloads: check the "artifacts" links

Comment: I did this and I believe I get the same problem.

Comment: check out http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2009/01/integrating-fluent-nhibernate-and.html

Comment: also http://www.orbitone.com/en/blog/archive/2009/06/23/adding-fluent-nhibernate-support-for-castle-windsor’s-nhibernate-integration.aspx

Comment: did you get the binaries from the build server? did you check the blogs I mentioned?

Comment: Thanks - i got the release build initially. but im using the developent version and it works beautifully! thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Two possibilities:

Most likely:
You have an outdated dll in the chain - Somewhere you have updated an assembly but not all of the library assemblies it requires.  Update your whole toolchain and verify the versions are correct.

Or:

You are referencing assembly "Alpha.dll", and calling something in it that exposes a type in assembly "Beta.dll".  Alpha references Beta, but your assembly only references Alpha.

In this case, you will get the above error message.  Most of the time you get this problem, you'll see a clearer message, (Add reference to Beta), but this happens sometimes.  If you figure out when, let me know!  To fix it, simply add a reference to Beta.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely it is version conflict, but I got this error while experimenting with MEF. While coping extensions to separate folder I forgotten about some dependant library. While trying to load extension this error was shown. To find out which library was missing I attached to AssemblyResolve event on current appdomain:

System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += ...

If you do so you will get information about assembly name and version that failed to load.

Answer (score 1):

You could check out the Horn project (http://code.google.com/p/hornget/ ). It will allow you to build castle, nhibernate and fleunt nhibernate and they should all work together.

It is in pre beta but the code is pritty solid and i've been using it for about the last month of two.

Colin G

Comment: Sadly , Hornget isn't supported anymore.